# Getting rid of duplicates from a query in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I am building a training record database and have come up against a duplication issue which I am not sure how to get rid of.

The database is structured so that each employee has a job title and few roles associated with them. Using junction tables, I have setup a set of trainings each role requires. My form currently shows this well. I can assign multiple roles to an employeee and the relative trainings show up on a subform. However, some trainings are associated with more than one role. For example, Course A is associated with Role A, Role B, and Role C. One employee can hold Role A and Role B, however, in this case, Course A shows up within the subform twice. How can I suppress/remove this duplication?

More context into how I am pulling this data:

1. I have a junction table called employeeXrole
2. I have another junction table called roleXcourse
3. I use a query to bring these two junction tables together. A subform, based on this query, is included in the main form with employee name and roles.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards

I could use find duplicate query but that is not a permanent solution.

**Edit**: Tables are added below:

**RoleXCourse_JT**

| ID | RoleID | CourseID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 12 |
| 4 | 22 | 1 |
| 5 | 22 | 11 |
| 6 | 23 | 11 |

**RoleXEmployee_JT**

| ID | RoleID | EmployeeID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | 22 | 1 |
| 3 | 23 | 1 |

What I have tried here is, that EmployeeID 1 holds roles 22 and 23, and role 22 needs courses 1 and 11, whereas role 23 needs course 11. this is the duplication I want to get rid of when displaying the data in a subform.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    RoleXEmployee_JT.EmployeeID, RoleXCourse_JT.CourseID, 
    RoleXCourse_JT.PositionID
FROM 
    RoleXEmployee_JT 
    INNER JOIN RoleXCourse_JT 
        ON RoleXEmployee_JT.PositionID = RoleXCourse_JT.PositionID;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your query as SQL text (not as an image).

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text tables. Why would you join two junction tables in a form? Should probably expect 'duplication'.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you for your reply.

Here is the SQL:

SELECT RoleXCourse_JT.CourseID, EmployeeT.EmployeeID, CourseT.CourseName, RoleXEmployeeQ.[Employee Name]
FROM ((RoleXEmployeeQ INNER JOIN RoleXCourse_JT ON RoleXEmployeeQ.PositionID = RoleXCourse_JT.PositionID) INNER JOIN CourseT ON RoleXCourse_JT.CourseID = CourseT.CourseID) INNER JOIN EmployeeT ON RoleXEmployeeQ.EmployeeID = EmployeeT.EmployeeID
ORDER BY CourseT.CourseName;

I am using EmployeeT and CourseT just to get the names of employees and courses.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your reply. I am joining two junction tables in a query so I can make the relationship between mandatory training and specific employee. Tables included in the question, as prompted.

Comment: Please, in future, include your query and any code directly into the answer. It is almost unreadable in a comment because it is unformatted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove all the columns from the SELECT list that make your "duplicates" not be real duplicates. Real duplicates are rows where **every** column is duplicate.

```sql
SELECT
    RoleXEmployee_JT.EmployeeID,
    RoleXCourse_JT.CourseID
FROM
    RoleXCourse_JT
    INNER JOIN RoleXEmployee_JT
        ON RoleXCourse_JT.RoleID = RoleXEmployee_JT.RoleID;
```

| EmployeeID | CourseID |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 11 | (duplicate) |
| 1 | 11 | (duplicate) |
| 2 | 6 |  |
| 2 | 8 |  |
| 2 | 12 |  |

If you include columns like `PositionID` or `RoleID` you will not get real duplicates:

| EmployeeID | CourseID | RoleID |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 22 |  |
| 1 | 11 | 22 | (no duplicate!) |
| 1 | 11 | 23 | (no duplicate!) |
| 2 | 6 | 6 |  |
| 2 | 8 | 6 |  |
| 2 | 12 | 6 |  |

Then you can apply the DISTINCT keyword to remove duplicates:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    RoleXEmployee_JT.EmployeeID,
    RoleXCourse_JT.CourseID
FROM
    RoleXCourse_JT
    INNER JOIN RoleXEmployee_JT
        ON RoleXCourse_JT.RoleID = RoleXEmployee_JT.RoleID;
```

| EmployeeID | CourseID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 12 |

Comment: You are right about RoleXEmployeeQ. I have change my EmployeeRoleTrainingQ to the one updated in my question. I was using other tables/queries just to get the employee, role, and course names but that can be done later.

Comment: Beautiful. Worked like a charm!! Much obliged.